# How to make sure RStudio to incorporate changes made in .bashrc

Tags: r, linux, rstudio

Currently in my RStudio I ran this code with this error:

```
> library(gtools)
> nrow(combinations(n=448,r=2,v=1:448,repeats.allowed=F))
Error: C stack usage  7971524 is too close to the limit
```

What I did, is I add this line

```
ulimit -s 16384
```

in my bashrc.

The R code above runs ok if I execute it with R console in my terminal.
But it still gives an error when I run it RStudio console.

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Have you tried `system("ulimit -s 16384")`?

Comment: I tried. It has no effect. Stil gives error.

Answer (score 4):

Adding `ulimit -s 16384` to `.bashrc` will only affect commands executed from `bash` shell. Like execution of `R console` from terminal (in same way you can execute `RStudio` from bash and it will work).

To apply `ulimit -s 16384` to a whole login session:

- add changes to `/etc/security/limits.conf` file.

```
*            soft    stack           16384                                   
*            hard    stack           16384
```

- logout/login to apply.
- run `RStudio` as usual and check.

Comment: @scamander, then for debug purposes in `R` code try to print the `ulimit` stack value. If the value is `16384`, so the issue not with current stack value. Since the `ulimit` **is a bash built-in** you can (try) execute it from `R` code with command `/bin/bash -i -c 'ulimit -a'`.